# What is the problem with this regex?

Tags: xml, regex

First, I'm not a regex expert, so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my regular expression:

```
<(list)(\b[^>]*)>(<\1\b[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>|.)*?<\/\1>
```

This is the input string:

```
...
<list title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...">
<li>
    <list title="Lorem adipiscing...">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    </list>
</li>
<li>
     <list title="Lorem ipsum...">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    </list>
</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</li>
</list>
...
```

I want to match the external `<list>` and catch all the content including the intertal `<list>` but when I try to read the group `\3` is empty althoug groups `\1` and `\2` are fine.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The problem with your regex is that you're using it to parse HTML.

Comment: To clarify cletus' answer (which is the correct answer for this question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: ...now you have *two* problems. /since we're bring out the cliches.

Comment: I know it looks similar but I'm afraid is XML. And the question is not about the benefits/drawbacks of parsing HTML/XML with regex. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem cannot be solved with a regular expression match. Seriously. I'm not just repeating the "don't parse HTML with regex" dogma; regular expressions are logically incapable of handling nested tags (which is *why* everyone says "don't parse HTML with regex")

The best idea I can give you is to use an XML parser. If you insist on solving this problem using regular expressions, you will wind up writing your own recursive-descent parser anyway, so you might as well take advantage of the work others have done on that problem already.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time of not just saying "you can't".

Comment: You're welcome... you didn't seem to be convinced by the comments, so I figured a bit of explanation might help.